# How do I coalesce .Max() for queries against empty collections in LINQ to EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an entity in my model that has an integer property:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    // ...other props
}
```

Now, for some subset of all the `Foo`s in the database, I want to select the highest `SortOrder` and add one - i.e. get the sort order for a new object added last in the collection - but if there are no `Foo`s in that subset, I want to end up with 0 - i.e. the sort order of a new object added to an empty collection.

Reading [this reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738551(v=vs.110).aspx), I got the impression that `.Max()` returns `null` if the collection over which it aggregates is empty, so I tried the following:

```
var sortOrder = context.Foos
    .Where(/* predicate for subset */)
    .Max(foo => foo.SortOrder) + 1
    ?? 0;
```

but that doesn't compile, since the return type of `.Max` is inferred to be `int` which can't be null coalesced.

However, if I just don't use the null coalescing, and assume that `.Max()` really returns `default(T)` (i.e. `0` in this case), then I'll end up with `1` instead of `0` for the empty case. Since this is a call to the database, I'd rather make do with one query.

It works just as I want it to if I make the property on `Foo` to be of type `int?`, but I don't want to do that since we don't allow `NULL` values in the database and I see no reason to allow them on the entity then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got the impression that .Max() returns null if the collection over
>   which it aggregates is empty

You get an `InvalidOperationException` which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351210(v=vs.100).ASPX)

*"InvalidOperationException... source does not contain any elements."*

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty(0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356814(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int maxSortOrder = context.Foos
    .Where(/* predicate for subset */)
    .Select(foo => foo.SortOrder + 1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max();
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to add one and get 0 in the empty case I think the default should be -1 instead of 0.

Comment: @juharr: have a look. OP mentions _" but if there are no Foos in that subset, I want to end up with 0"_. But you're right, it seems that he wants to add 1 to existing values.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with something quite similar to this.